# Drawdown calculator - decimal place bug

Tags: python, statistics, finance

I have looked at a lot of other posts on drawdowns and not found a solution for this.

I have a drawdown calculator below that appears to work, but is apparently not accurate.
It returns the drawdowns for a array of returns.

I wanted the 2nd highest drawdown for this list (to 4 decimal places).

However, apparently my number is inaccurante.

I get -0.0300
and the correct answer is -0.0298

and I can't figure out what is wrong.

the code:

```
import numpy as np

def all_drawdowns(rets):
    dd_results = []

    cum_rets = rets.cumsum()
    i = np.argmax(np.maximum.accumulate(cum_rets) - cum_rets) # end of the period
    if i == 0:
        return dd_results
    j = np.argmax(rets[:i]) # start of period
    max_dd = cum_rets[i] - cum_rets[j]
    dd_results.append(max_dd)
    l_rets = rets[:j]
    r_rets = rets[i+1:]
    
    if len(l_rets) > 1:
        dd_results.extend(all_drawdowns(l_rets))
    
    if len(r_rets) > 1:
        dd_results.extend(all_drawdowns(r_rets))
        
    return sorted(dd_results)

rets_task = np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, -0.01, -0.02, 0.04, 0.05, -0.02, -0.02, 0.03])

all_drawdowns(rets_task)
```

The second element of the returned array should  be -0.30 as I mentioned, but should be -0.0298 (but it's not clear why.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think the right answer is -0.0298?

Comment: Because the answer to question was revealed to be -0.0298  (This is already all submitted, so I've officially got it wrong, but I don't know why/how)

Comment: If the answer is supposed to the drawdown amount (as opposed to a percentage), then the answer can only have two decimal places.  No amount of addition or subtraction of those values will ever create more decimal places.

Comment: Out of interest, how would it work with percentages?

Comment: Percentages aren't better.  Both of the top two drawdowns are 50%.  Do you have an initial value for this investment?  Are those numbers supposed to be dollar returns, or percentage changes?

Comment: Percentage changes. So the way you would typically consider returns of an investment.

I might be miss-remembering, as it's now closed and not viewable.
So that's why I asked to double check if you got it in other method (because I've tried others too). getting pct_change from these, etc..

Comment: Then you can't just do a `cumsum`.  You need to apply compound interest.  I think that's the only change you'd need to make.  I'll try it.

Comment: I tried that too with the folllowing instead:

cum_rets = (1+ rets).cumprod() - 1

But maybe that isn't correct

Comment: I don't know.  That looks right to me, but the answer is even farther negative.  I guess you'll need to ask an instructor.